# How I can access a custom MFT using activatable class ID string inside a WRL?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, c++-cx, ms-media-foundation

The link [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Store app using WRL and Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj872764.aspx)

provides example of a custom MFT creation and using it as activatable class. Inside C# code the MFT is referenced using activatable class ID string like this

```
mediaCapture.AddEffectAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, "GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect", null);
```

the MediaCapture knows about the MFT with the string `"GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect"`. 
How does the MediaCapture reference the MFT only with this string?

I need to know the process because I am working on a project which requires creating video from images (using WRL) for which i am following this [Developing a WinRT component to create a video file using Media Foundation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/03/06/developing-a-winrt-component-to-create-a-video-file-using-media-foundation.aspx). But before i write `IMFSample` to `SinkWriter` I need it to pass it through a custom activatable MFT class. If I pass the activatable class ID from C# to the WRL class will I be able to reference the custom MFT?
[Basic MFT Processing Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes referencing an MFT using CLSID. But is it possible to extract any CLSID with just the activatable classID string?

So to summarize, How can I use a custom MFT to process an `IMFSample` using the activatable classID string in side a WRL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the Windows::Foundation::ActivateInstance function inside AddEffectAsync to create a new instance of the MoCOM object.

Since you want to use the MFT outside of a Media Foundation topology you will need to configure it to process the data. This starts with getting the stream identifiers, setting the media types and getting the buffer requirements. Once the MFT is properly setup you can then start processing the samples.

As an aside MFTs are specifically designed to be framework agnostic. Back in the DirectShow days there was no easy way to use DirectShow filters outside of the filter-graph. We specifically designed the MFT architecture (based on DMO technology that originated on the DSound team) to make them easy to setup and use independently of a topology manager.

[ActivateInstance Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244937.aspx)

[Basic MFT Processing Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965264(v=vs.85).aspx)

I hope this helps,

James

Comment: I have used the following code. HSTRING hst; WindowsCreateString(L"SomeEffectsMFT.Effects", 22, &hst); ComPtr<IMFTransform> MFT; ComPtr<IInspectable> inspectable; HRESULT hr = ActivateInstance(hst, &inspectable); This way I have been able to see the class name that implemented the IMFTransform in 'inspectable'. Now can you tell me how do I reference the class that implemented the custom MFT so that I can follow the 'Basic MFT Processing Model' ?

Comment: I have been able to access the custom MFT using this part. ComPtr<IMFTransform> MFT; HRESULT hr = inspectable.As(&MFT); using the variable MFT I can call functions of the custom MFT.