# How to use an in-process IMFTransform with WinRT MediaPlayer::AddVideoEffect via activatableClassId

Tags: windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation, c++-winrt

WinRT's [Windows::Media::Playback::MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer?view=winrt-19041) has support to adding video and audio effects (much like [IMFMediaEngine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfmediaengine/nn-mfmediaengine-imfmediaengine)), however I can't find a way to use existing IMFTransform's that I already use with [IMFMediaEngineEx::InsertVideoEffect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfmediaengine/nf-mfmediaengine-imfmediaengineex-insertaudioeffect) in [MediaPlayer::AddVideoEffect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.addvideoeffect?view=winrt-19041)

MediaPlayer::AddVideoEffect() only takes a string for the "activatableClassId", whereas IMFMediaEngineEx::InsertVideoEffect() allows me to pass in a pointer to my local IMFTransform directly.  I don't want to registry a DLL with the system for the class to be activatable, I just want the IMFTransform to be registered locally in-process so that it can be discovered by the classId.

I've searched online but there is very little information.  All I found was this [Microsoft thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/814c16f4-0dc5-4307-9e6a-e688084c6b99/how-to-define-customer-interface-in-mft-media-foundation-transform-and-how-to-use-the-customer?forum=winappswithcsharp), an old article showing [CGreyScale MFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-store-app-using-wrl-and-media-foundation?view=vs-2019) using WRL, and this [useful repository](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/Media%20extensions%20sample/%5BC%2B%2B%5D-Media%20extensions%20sample/C%2B%2B/MediaExtensions) which uses an appxmanifest to registry the classes (not what I want to do).

These example seem useful and I implemented the decoration around my existing MFT however the example relies on registering the activatableClassId externally so I still can't tell how to do it in-process.  The only thing I could find was [RoRegisterActivationFactories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/roapi/nf-roapi-roregisteractivationfactories)() but there's very little information about this so I'm not sure.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the IMFTransform in MediaPlayer::AddVideoEffect() method to add the video effect?

Comment: Yes exactly, but importantly I want it to be discoverable locally without having to specify it in the appxmanifest

Comment: Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-store-app-using-wrl-and-media-foundation?view=vs-2019) of the CGreyScale MFT using WRL, even if the samples are dated and are targeted for Windows 8, but the documentation does provide a way for being able to locally reference and utilize a MFTransform through the setup and then calling the transform by the following format ("Namespace.ActivatableClass") so for this document, it is declared as "GrayscaleTransform.GrayScaleEffect".

Comment: If this does not work, the recommended process is to declare the .dll as an Extension in your appxmanifest. This is similar to what is shown in the samples provided. The processes for using a C++ MFTransform with a UWP application can either:
have it declared in-code by the .Midl file and ActivatableClass specifications added to the Transform source files (which is shown inside of the tutorial code in the links above). Declare use of the MFTransform .dll as an Extension through use of the InProcessServer tag.

Comment: Thanks @Faywang-MSFT well my application doesn't necessarily have an appxmanifest.  I'm building a plugin for Unity, so basically I'm building a self-contained DLL video player plugin.  This is for Windows desktop platform (using WinRT libraries) not UWP.  Is there a path for this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: You can check the answer of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26599000), it provides the additional information and links regarding the process of basic MFT processing model and the use of Windows::Foundation::ActivateInstance. Can it address your question appropriately?

Comment: 1/2: Thanks @Faywang-MSFT for the link.  I'm afraid it doesn't help me though.  The link shows how to use an MFT in general - but I want to use it specifically with the MediaPlayer::AddVideoEffect method  which ONLY takes an activatableClassId string.  I have my MFT which I want to use, but I need to register it with the system so that I can use the classId string in that API to instantiate it.  I can't work out how to register it.  I want to want to register is as an extension DLL as it is encapsulated within my general plugin DLL.

Comment: 2/2: I just want to be able to do something like the old MFTRegisterLocal() or MFTRegisterLocalByCLSID() so that when I call MediaPlayer::AddVideoEffect() in the same process, it can find the MFT.  The InProcessServer tag approach sounds promising, but my 'application' is actually just a DLL since I am building a plugin for Unity which other developers use.  So the 'appxmanifest' method isn't suitable as each user would have to create it for their app.

Comment: I tried calling RoRegisterActivationFactories() from my DLL, but sadly it just returns 'class not registered'

Answer (score 0):

Since the MediaPlayer API is WinRT, it will expect to use WinRT activated objects for effects. Alternatively, the lower level win32 MF Media Engine allows you to pass in an IMFActivate for any custom activation.

There are two ways to activate the MFT with WinRT:

1. Register the MFT to the registry and reference the CLSID, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/registering-and-enumerating-mfts#registering-mfts).
2. Registration-Free WinRT(which requires the use of an application manifest), you can refer to this [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/).

Unfortunately, this means that there is an appmanifest requirement if you wish to register the MFT in-process.